# SQL Edit Distance: How have you handled Fuzzy String Matching using SQL in the past?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have always wanted to ask for your views on this topic, so here we go:

My team just provided me with a list of customer accounts we need to match with other databases and the main challenge we face is the fact our list is non-standarized so we call similarly but differently the same accounts than in our databases. For example:

```
My_List.Customers_Name         Customers_Database.Customers_Name
-                              -
Charles Schwab                 Charles Schwab Corporation
```

So for example, I use Jaro Wrinkler Similarity function and Edit Distance in order to gather a list of similar strings and then manually match the accounts if needed. My question is:

Which rules/filters do you apply to the results of the fuzzy data matching in order to reduce the amount of manual match?

I am refering to rules like:
If the string has more than 20 characters and Edit Distance <= 1 then it will probably be the same so consider it a match. If the string has less than 4 characters and Edit Distance >0 then it will probably not be the same account so consider it a mismatch.

These rules I apply are completely made up from my side, I am wondering if there are some standard convention for applying text string fuzzy matching in order to only retrieve useful results and reduce manual match workload.

If there are not, could you tell your experience and how you handled this before?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a few times. It's hugely dependent on the data sets, and the rules change every time.

My process is:

- select a random set of sample records to check my rule set - large enough to be representative, small enough to be able to scan visually.
- create a "match" table with "original", "match" and "confidence score" columns.
- write the rules, as "insert" or "update" statements to create records in the "match" table
- run the rules on my sample data set
- evaluate the matches on the samples. Tweak, add, configure the rules.
- rinse & repeat

The "rules" depend hugely on the data set. Commonly I use the following:

- strip out punctuation
- apply common substitutions (e.g. "Corp" becomes "Corporation")
- split into separate words; apply fraction of each exact match out of 10 (so "Charles Schwab" matching "Charles Schwab Corporeation" would be 2/3 = 7 points, "HSBC" matching "HSBC" is 1/1 = 10 points
- split into separate words; apply fraction of each close match out of 5 (so "Chls Schwab" matching "Charles Schwab Corporation" would be 2/3 = 3 points, "HSBC" matching "HSCB" is 1/1 = 5 points)